# fetch post returns unsupported_grant_type error

Tags: javascript, http, content-type, fetch-api, bad-request

I want to login, but I have an error:
POST http://xxx/Token 400 (Bad Request)
{error: "unsupported_grant_type"}

```
 login = () => {
        const newItem = {
            "Username": this.state.Username,
            "Password": this.state.Password,
            "grant_type": "password"
        }
        if (this.state.Username && this.state.Password) {
            fetch("http://xxx/Token", {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(newItem)
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `body: JSON.stringify(newItem)` are contradictions! You should not tell the server (via the Content-Type header) to expect form-urlencoded data, but then send JSON data. The server could easily by confused by that, and try to apply the wrong method to parse the incoming data. If you want to send JSON data, then send the correct Content-Type header (i.e. `application/json`) along with it.

This is likely to be the cause of the error you're seeing. There is a strong chance that the server cannot understand the data you've sent it, since it's trying to interpret it as form-urlencoded data. Then the first validation check it makes happens to be to check the grant_type value. When it finds (as it sees things) that you haven't submitted any value at all for that parameter, it returns an error saying it can't process your request because it needs you to send a valid grant_type value.

Setting

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

in your headers should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't enough context to answer this question as the error response is coming from an unknown service. But based on it being a bad request response mentioning grant_type and you're sending a grant_type in your request body, I'd assume "password" isn't a valid type.

I suggest you refer to the documentation of the endpoint you're using.